# How to subscribe to service that receives data from router (master-detail scenario)?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2 and typescript, so this may be an easy one for any experienced folks! I develop a master-detail App using the Angular Heroes tutorial as a starter. I added a http service that calls a rest api. It properly lists decisions made in our town ( Antwerp Belgium :) ). Now when I click to view the details, the resulting json object is 'undefined'.

In my decision-detail.component.ts file, I have an error at  `decision => this.decision = decision,` *"Type 'Decision[]' is not assignable to type 'Decision'."*

```
export class DecisionDetailComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() decision: Decision;

errorMessage: string;

constructor(
    private _decisionService: DecisionService,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._decisionService.getDecision(id)
                         .subscribe(
                             decision => this.decision = decision,
                             error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);                      
}
```

}

Here's my decision.service.ts code:

`getDecision (id: number) {
        return this.http.get(this._decisionsUrl+id)
                        .map(res => <Decision[]> res.json().data)
                        .do(data => console.log(data)) //eyeball results in the console
                        .catch(this.handleError)`

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Deleted the @input and declared decisions as a property in the class.